# Custom row background color on AlertDialog adapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog with an ArrayAdapter to show a list of items for the user to select form (single choice).  However, I would like to show which item was previously selected.  Since selecting an item automatically closes the dialog, my thought was to set a custom background color for the previously selected item.  Below is a mockup of what I'm hoping to achieve:

[image]

The code I have currently is this:

```
private void showCustomAlert(int alertNumber, int parentTaskId) {
    Log.w(LOGTAG, showCustomAlert);         
    int alertNumberID = Integer.parseInt(task1_id);
    if (alertNumber==2) alertNumberID = Integer.parseInt(task2_id);
    else if (alertNumber==3) alertNumberID = Integer.parseInt(task3_id);
    else if (alertNumber==4) alertNumberID = Integer.parseInt(task4_id);

    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
    builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Task:");


    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(thisActivity,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    for (int i=0; i<taskList.size(); i++) {
        BT_item tmpItem = taskList.get(i);
        if (BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(tmpItem.getJsonObject(),"task_parent","").equalsIgnoreCase(parentTaskId + ""))
            arrayAdapter.add(BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(tmpItem.getJsonObject(),"task_name",""));
    }

    builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int taskSelected) {
                    Log.w(LOGTAG, "task selected"); 

                }
            });
    builderSingle.show();

}
```

Comment: There is a difference between making a selection on the adapter and simply making the view look selected. Maybe you could find the view that has the item you want to select and mark the view there as selected?

Comment: Correct - I'm trying to make it "look" selected, not to actually select it.  The idea is for the user to change their selection if desired, while showing them what they had previously selected first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..   instead of your  builderSingle.setAdapter use below line

```
                builderSingle
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(display_array, selected_pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int pos) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            selected_pos = pos; 

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
```

display_array is your items which you what to display in dialog that's in array..